# Putting all columns of a data frame into a single histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data table like this

```
ind1 ind2 ind3 indn
0.1 0.5 1.0 0.0
0.9 0.6 1.0 0.1
0.9 0.7 0.9 0.3
```

Each column is an individual, each row is the individuals genotype probability at that row's genome coordinate.

I want to make a single, stacked histogram where the x-axis is GP ranging from 0 to 1, and the y axis is number of sites in that range (with the stacks colored based on the individual they originated from). I previously did something like this before:

```
plN <- ggplot(ndf, aes(x=GP, fill=indiv, color=indiv)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)
plot(plN)
```

by in that case, there were only two columns.

```
ind1 0.1
ind1 0.9
ind1 0.9
ind2 0.5
ind2 0.6
ind2 0.7...
```

Comment: The general answer to this is to reshape your example dataset into that second format, with one column for the grouping variable and another for the value.  I didn't see an exact duplicate but see, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940156/ggplot-geom-bar-where-x-multiple-columns) or search "ggplot2 bar multiple columns".

Comment: `ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = everything()), aes(x=value, fill=name, color=name)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, can you explain what this means, I don't know how tidyr works. Do I have to replace value or name with something? Right now I do not have any row name, and the column names are just the individual names.

Comment: No just replace `df` with your dataframe name which I guess is `ndf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aosmith commented the usual (tidy) way is to get data in long format for plotting. You can get data in long format by using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`. It will get the data in two-column format where `name` column is the column name and `value` column is the value in that column.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(ndf, cols = everything()), 
       aes(x=value, fill=name, color=name)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)
```